# Serpent Cipher 128bits (Example rounds on any plaintext/key)

Tags: encryption, serpent

Is there are any possibility to see trace(example) of Serpent Encryption/Decryption on concrete plaintext/key example, (not code implementation) or at least animation of steps. During reading of Serpent I found article on IDEA Encryption with full round description on concrete plaintext https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEA which explains how roundkey forms, encryption/decryption goes which is enough to start implementation and verify solution. But there are nothing likely about Serpent, only description of S-Box/IP constants but nowhere about brief plaintext example like in previous IDEA on Wikipedia. So it's nearly impossible to understand how Serpent encrypts and decrypts plaintext. Also there is an in-depth step description of AES http://www.formaestudio.com/rijndaelinspector/archivos/Rijndael_Animation_v4_eng.swf Where is it possible to see on a same examples but for Serpent? The only thing is available is test vectors but it is not a rounds description like in articles above. Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the AES submission of Serpent? It's easily available from the Serpent home page.